# angular material MatChipInputEvent error in console

Tags: angular

chip.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
    import {ENTER, COMMA} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';


    @Component({
    selector: 'app-chip',
    templateUrl: './chip.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chip.component.css']
    })
    export class ChipComponent {
    constructor() { }
    visible: boolean = true;
    selectable: boolean = true;
    removable: boolean = true;
    addOnBlur: boolean = true;

    // Enter, comma
    separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];

    keywords = [];


    add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
        let input = event.input;
        let value = event.value;

        // Add our keyword
        if ((value || '').trim()) {
        this.keywords.push(value.trim());
        }

        // Reset the input value
        if (input) {
        input.value = '';
        }
    }

    remove(keyword: any): void {
        let index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);

        if (index >= 0) {
        this.keywords.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    }
```

chip.component.html

```
    <mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable"
                [removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(keyword)">
        {{keyword}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="Keywords"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" />
    </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
```

errors in console:

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'selectable' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-chip'.
    1. If 'mat-chip' is an Angular component and it has 'selectable' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-chip' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" class="demo-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [ERROR ->][selectable]="selectable"
                [removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(keyword)">
        {{ke"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@2:47
    Can't bind to 'removable' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-chip'.
    1. If 'mat-chip' is an Angular component and it has 'removable' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-chip' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("st #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable"
                [ERROR ->][removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(keyword)">
        {{keyword}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@3:13
    'mat-icon' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
                [removable]="removable" (remove)="remove(keyword)">
        {{keyword}}
        [ERROR ->]<mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="K"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@5:6
    'mat-chip' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-chip' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-chip' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        [ERROR ->]<mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable"
                [removable]="remova"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@2:4
    Can't bind to 'matChipInputFor' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="Keywords"
            [ERROR ->][matChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            "): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@8:11
    Can't bind to 'matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
        <input placeholder="Keywords"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [ERROR ->][matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
    "): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@9:11
    Can't bind to 'matChipInputAddOnBlur' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("ChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            [ERROR ->][matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" />
    </mat-chip-l"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@10:11
    'mat-chip-list' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-chip-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-chip-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
    [ERROR ->]<mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable"
    "): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@1:2
    'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword"): ng:///AppModule/ChipComponent.html@0:0
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:2426)
        at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20600)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26146)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26133)
        at compiler.js:26076
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26076)
        at compiler.js:25986
        at Object.then (compiler.js:2417)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
```

Here i am trying to integrate angular material **MatChipInputEvent**
In my terminal it is compiling successfully but in console it is showing template 
parsing error.

Am i missing any other import .

I have done the same from angular documentations.

Please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

you should do this in your app module: "import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips'"

Answer (score 3):

When you use an Angular Material component, you have to add the import inside the module concerned.

```
import {..., MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations                                                            : [
        ...
    ], imports: [
        ..., MatChipsModule
    ], providers: [
        ...
    ], exports: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the working answer for me is

```
 // Reset the input value
        if (event.input) {
       event.input.value = '';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
if (input) {
   input.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code, you import like this

> import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material';

for this reason, you faced the issue `please correct import statement`

> import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material/chips';